# Excel - VBA : How do I check if the last character of every single cell is > (superior sign)

Tags: excel, vba

How do I check in VBA-Excel whether the last character of every single cell of my sheet is a `>` (superior sign).

Below is what I've been doing so far.

```
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("C1", Range(">" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not IsNumeric(Mid(c, 3, 1)) Then
        MsgBox ("Found !!!")
    End If
    Exit For
Next c
```

Comment: Do you mean whether **every cell** ends with a ">"?  Or every **used** cell ends with a ">"?  Or every used cell **in column C** ends with a ">"?  Or, with all of those cases, do you mean **any** cell rather than **every** cell?

Comment: Thanks YowE3K for your reply. I mean "Every cell" in Column C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Like` operator with the wild-card `*` as a prefix.

Inside your `For` loop, to check if a cell has a `>` at the end, use:

```
Dim C As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet3") ' <-- modify "Sheet3" to your sheet's name
    ' loop through column C, from C1 until last cell with data in Column C (including blank cells in the middle)
    For Each C In Range("C1:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        If C.Value Like "*>" Then '<-- if the end of the cell is ">"
            MsgBox "Found !!! at Cell " & C.Address
        End If
    Next C
End With
```

Comment: I tried      `DO     If C.Value Like "*>" Then
        MsgBox "Found !!! at Cell " & C.Address
        End If          LOOP` but it's not working

Comment: @Alice what error are you getting ? are you looking for `>` inside the cell as `Value` or `Formula` ? see edited code if it works now

Comment: I'm writing that code in a Macro (ALT+11), and there, I created a UserFrom with a Command Button. So I pasted your code into `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`

Comment: ...and I got Runtime Error 9 : Subscript out of range. Sorry I didn't see your comment that I had to change that "Sheet3" with my real sheet name. It's working perfect. Thanks !!!

Comment: @Alice at what line ? have you chnages "Sheet3" with your sheet's name in the line `With Worksheets("Sheet3") ` ?

Comment: It's working good. but I have over 2000 cells to go through. is there any way to modify your code in order to only get the cell that doesn't have ">" at the end, and direct the result out to a txt file. So that I can just read the txt file and locate the exact cell to add the ">" sign.  As now, what I'm facing is I'm stuck with the msgbox and I need to maintain ENTER key in order to keep going through all the 2000 cell one by one.

Comment: @Alice this sound like a new **SO** post. I think i've answered exactly what you requested for in this post, and you can mark this as "Answer" and close this one (otherwise we will never close posts here). At your new post, add your modifed code, and describe what you want to achieve, this will allow other users (except me) a chance to help you.

Comment: Why Except you?? If you know how to do that, you can just reply, it doens't matter !!!  Anyway, Can you explain me your code cause I also want to learn, not only doing copy/paste?

Comment: @Alice since this is not the scope of your post, in the future when other users will look for answers for similar posts they will not be able to get the correct answer for this post. **SO** is bigger than just you and I, it's a DB for knowledge, where users can find help with topics they are having problems with.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me a code, but I'd like to learn as well. I'm just asking you if you can comment your code especially `For Each C In Range("C1:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)` that's all I want.

Comment: @Alice OK, that's more than fair, see my comments in my edited code

Comment: Thanks so much. What's WRONG !!!. I'm unable to ask another Question. !!!  You have reached your question limit. How do I sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `right` function to get last character and check if it equals `chr(62)` which is `>`

You can modify you code in a way below:

```
Right(ActiveCell.Value, 1) = Chr(62)
```

It will return `TRUE` if last character is `>`

Answer (score 0):

First you use the active sheet. Then you try to find the last row in column "C". Once you find it, you start looping over the range from C1 to C&lastRow. There, if you find the sign ">" on the right you print "found" and the row number in the immediate window. Then you exit the sub.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim c           As Range
    Dim lastRow     As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(lastRow, 3))
            If Right(c, 1) = ">" Then
                Debug.Print "FOUND"
                Debug.Print c.Row
            Exit For
            End If


        Next c

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read your question title, you said that you want to check if the right most character in each cell in column C is ">". Right?

The I don't understand why you are using Exit For once a ">" is found any cell though it is used at wrong place as it will be triggered after first loop.

If you want to achieve what your question title says, try this...

The following code will check each cell in column C and return a "Found!" if the last character was a ">" or will return "Not Found!".

```
Sub CheckTheLastCharacterInString()
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D1:D" & lr).Value = Evaluate("IF(RIGHT(C1:C" & lr & ",1)="">"",""Found!"",""Not Found!"")")
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is not working. I pasted it into Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() and have not effect.

Comment: Place this code on a Standard Module and then in the CommandButton1_Click event you just need to place a single line of code like Call CheckTheLastCharacterInString. Please read the description I added along with the code in the answer to know how does this code work.

Comment: Also the code will return Found or Not Found in column D on the sheet.